# Error: Successful login; however, it always redirects to the login page instead of admin page

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

My problem is: 
I couldn't figure out why it is always redirecting to the login page even I successfully login, not direct to my admin page.

I use mongoDB as my database and nodejs as my backend.

First, I tried to do something with csrf. It wasn't successful, then I deleted it (I may come back to it later). So I moved on. However, I got this problem right after I deleted csrf. I don't know what causes it and how to fix it.

I even tried to run my old code (before use csrf) on my laptop. Separately from my PC which I wrote code with csrf. It would not work as well. 
This is so weird for me. I never seen this problem before.

Please help me to solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add a code snippet to show the problem you are facing. These links would be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It has the exact problem like this post. I don't understand its answer. Can anyone really help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045058/continuous-redirecting-to-login-page-using-passport-node-js#_=_